# Program with many piped subprocesses started in a loop crashes after some time

Tags: rust, command, pipe, runtime-error

This program is supposed to keep looking for a number of processes via the system process table (using piped commands `ps aux | grep <proc_name> | grep -v grep | grep -v <program_name>` and start the process if it's not there or killed.

After running for some time, the program crashes with error "Resource Temporarily Unavailable".

I think it's because of a file handle leak somewhere but exactly where, I'm not sure.

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::env;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let names: Vec<String> = env::args().skip(1).collect();

    loop {
        for proc_name in &names {
            resurrect(proc_name.as_str());
        }
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
    }
}

fn resurrect(proc_name: &str) {
    let mut ps_child = Command::new("ps")
        .arg("aux")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to spawn ps");

    let ps_stdout = ps_child
        .stdout
        .take()
        .expect("failed to take out ps stdout");

    let mut grep_proc_child = Command::new("grep")
        .arg(proc_name)
        .stdin(Stdio::from(ps_stdout))
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect(format!("failed to spawn grep {}", proc_name).as_str());

    let grep_proc_stdout = grep_proc_child
        .stdout
        .take()
        .expect(format!("failed to take out grep {}", proc_name).as_str());

    grep_proc_child
        .wait()
        .expect("failed to wait on grep_proc_child");

    let mut grep_grep_child = Command::new("grep")
        .arg("-v")
        .arg("grep")
        .stdin(Stdio::from(grep_proc_stdout))
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to spawn grep -v grep");
    let grep_grep_stdout = grep_grep_child
        .stdout
        .take()
        .expect("failed to take out grep_grep_child stdout");
    grep_grep_child
        .wait()
        .expect("failed to wait on grep_grep_child");

    let grep_self_child = Command::new("grep")
        .arg("-v")
        .arg("process_checker")
        .stdin(Stdio::from(grep_grep_stdout))
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("failed to spawn grep_self");

    let grep_self_out = grep_self_child
        .wait_with_output()
        .expect("failed to wait on grep_self");

    let proc_str = String::from_utf8(grep_self_out.stdout).expect("failed to convert to str");
    let proc_id = proc_str
        .split_whitespace()
        .filter(|st| !st.trim().is_empty())
        .nth(1);

    if let Some(running_proc_id) = proc_id {
        println!("{}: {}", proc_name, running_proc_id);
    } else {
        let proc_name_full = format!("/path/to/my/binaries/{}.jar", proc_name);
        Command::new("nohup")
            .arg("java")
            .arg("-jar")
            .arg(proc_name_full)
            .spawn()
            .expect(format!("couldn't resurrect: {}", proc_name).as_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: You wait for neither `ps_child` nor the result of `nohup`.

Comment: I added `ps_child.wait().expect("failed to wait on ps");` right before `grep_proc_child` but then the program freezes. Why does it freeze?

Comment: Presumably because you've caused a deadlock. Your program is waiting for the child process to finish but your child process cannot finish until it is done writing output, but you haven't started the next process to consume the output. Try waiting for each stage of the pipeline in reverse order from how you started them.

Comment: I'll try that. BTW, why marked this question as duplicate? This one brings a different concern out of same activity.

Comment: Because the problem is exactly the same, and is solved by the answer you already received. You have to wait for the process to exit or else you have leaked file handles. We don't need separate questions for every unique time that someone forgets to call `wait`.

Comment: I put a `wait` after where the second command in pipe consumes the output of first. That seems to work and solve the dead-lock problem. However, if I put the `wait` on the resurrected process `new_proc_child.wait().expect("couldn't wait for new_proc_child");` (after the very last line) this watchdog program freezes right after the starting the child process. Do I even need to wait for this child process? If it gets killed, will this watchdog program leak file handles and crash again? How to safely start a new process and not crash this program?

Comment: *How to safely start a new process and not crash this program?* — that seems like a reasonable new top-level question to ask. Please make sure to create a small [MCVE] that focuses on that specific aspect of the problem (it doesn't need any piping / grepping, for example).

Comment: Ok, here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602145/how-to-write-a-simple-and-reliable-watchdog-program-in-rust

Comment: I'm afraid that the question, as you've asked it, will be overly broad, and thus not a good fit for Stack Overflow. My gut tells me that if the child process actually does die, then it will no longer be counted against your ulimit quota (I don't think file descriptors come into play) so you'd be OK. Instead, I might be worried that the child process won't continue running if the watchdog is killed.

Comment: Yes I came to the same understanding on both parts. I'm fine with child process getting killed when watchdog does because watchdog is supposed to be running all the time. Thanks for your help.